# Access join with missing field

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

Hello, I am trying to build a query in MS Access 2016. I have a master list of claim numbers (about 4 million claims). I have 6 other tables for different vendors. Each has claim number, payment year and payment amount. The attached image gives a simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish. The end result would have claim number, payment year and six payment amount columns for each of vendor payments on that claim in that year. I am not very familiar with SQL, but think I need to use that to accomplish this. I tried to force it by creating a table with claim number and all possible payment year combinations. This would give me the necessary two fields to join to the other tables. But, it exceeded the 2G size limit. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: SqlZim. thanks for the edit!

Comment: Give us more information about the data structure

Comment: Each table has a claim number (short-text). The master list has all claim numbers, but no years field. The vendors only have those claims for which they had payments. They have the claim number, the payment year (number) and payment amount (number). Not all vendors will have all claims. Not all claims will have vendor payments. Multiple vendors and multiple years can have payments on a given claim. Does that help?

Comment: sounds to me that your database is not normalize as you have 6 tables for different vendors.. Ideally you should have a claims table, vendors table  and claim_payment table

Answer (score 0):

The database structure is not normalized, but anyway, try this:

```
with cl_y as
(Select ClaimNo, Year 
From m,v1,v2
Where m.claimno = v1.claimno
And m.claimno = v2.claimno)

Select ClaimNo,Year,v1.Payment,v2.Payment,(v1.Payment + v2.Payment) as Total
From  cl_y
Left Outer Join v1 ON cl_y.ClaimNo = v1.ClaimNo
Left Outer Join v2 On cl_y.ClaimNo = v2.ClaimNo
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the time and feedback. I tried this on the sample data and get an error: "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'Delete', insert, procedure, select or update

Answer (score 0):

I agree with maSTA, not ideal design. Should be one table of all vendor claims with another field for the VendorID. However, you can replicate 'normalized' structure by building a UNION query with the 6 vendor tables. Must build UNION query in SQLView of query builder.

```
SELECT ClaimNo, [Year] AS YearPay, Payment, "Vendor1" AS Vendor FROM Vendor1  
UNION SELECT ClaimNo, [Year], Payment, "Vendor2" FROM Vendor2  
UNION SELECT ClaimNo, [Year], Payment, "Vendor3" FROM Vendor3  
UNION SELECT ClaimNo, [Year], Payment, "Vendor4" FROM Vendor4  
UNION SELECT ClaimNo, [Year], Payment, "Vendor5" FROM Vendor5  
UNION SELECT ClaimNo, [Year], Payment, "Vendor6" FROM Vendor6
UNION SELECT ClaimNo, Null, Null, Null FROM Master;
```

Then use that query in a CROSSTAB query to 'denormalize' by pivoting to the desired result. Adding the SELECT line pulling from Master should allow inclusion of claims that don't yet have payments.

Suggested CROSSTAB:

```
TRANSFORM First(ClaimUNION.[Payment]) AS FirstOfPayment
SELECT ClaimUNION.[ClaimNo], ClaimUNION.[YearPay], Sum(ClaimUNION.[Payment]) AS TotalPayment
FROM ClaimUNION
GROUP BY ClaimUNION.[ClaimNo], ClaimUNION.[YearPay]
PIVOT ClaimUNION.[Vendor];
```

A drawback to this may be that there will be empty rows even for claims that do have payments. An alternative approach is to not include Master in the UNION but to join the CROSSTAB to Master in a third query. Or join the UNION to Master and build CROSSTAB on that:

```
TRANSFORM First(ClaimUNION.Payment) AS FirstOfPayment
SELECT Master.ClaimNo, ClaimUNION.YearPay, Sum(ClaimUNION.Payment) AS 
TotalPayment
FROM ClaimUNION RIGHT JOIN Master ON ClaimUNION.ClaimNo = Master.ClaimNo
GROUP BY Master.ClaimNo, ClaimUNION.YearPay
PIVOT ClaimUNION.Vendor;
```

Year is a reserved word in Access. Should not use reserved words as names for anything, better would be YearPay.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will have claim number that don't yet have a payment, so I'll try a different route. Thanks for the tip on not using year.

Comment: Okay, maybe not as complicated as I feared. See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried on a subset and I keep getting prompted to input values for my payment field. Not sure why. Also, does it matter if the field names are not identical? For example, one provider uses "ClaimNo", another uses "ClaimNumber", etc.

Comment: If you have field in each table named Payment, should not be prompted. No matter if field names are different - the first SELECT line sets the field names the UNION query will display - note the aliases YearPay and Vendor.

Comment: I continue to get prompted to enter BR_RTL_FEES. I must be missing something. There are many amount fields with different names.   SELECT CLM_NUM2 AS ClaimNo, ANALYSIS_YR, BR_RTL_FEES AS "Amount", "BR_Retail"  FROM Vendor1  
UNION SELECT CLM_NUM2 AS ClaimNo, ANALYSIS_YR, UR_RTL_FEES AS "Amount", "UR_Retail"  FROM Vendor2 

UNION SELECT ClaimNumber AS ClaimNo, Null, Null, Null FROM Master;

Comment: Don't enclose field names, natural or alias, in quote marks. You did not enclose alias ClaimNo in quote marks, why are you enclosing other field names in quote marks? Don't need to repeat the aliases on each SELECT line - won't hurt just not needed. The first line determines field names used. See my example again.

Comment: I gave up on Access and tried something else. Thanks anyway!